# Accessing Javascript Object from HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to work out how to get a JavaScript object method to fire when a button is clicked. Part of the JavaScript is as follows:

```
function TaxiShare() {
this.register = function () { 
var username = get_name_value('name', 'user1'); 
$.post('http://website/users', {
    USERNAME: username
        }, function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (obj.status == "fail") {
                alert('User ' + username + ' is already registered.');
            } else {
                alert('User ' + username + ' has been successfully registered.');
            }
        }
        );
    }; 
}
```

I am used to having HTML like the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onClick="nameOfFunction">
```

What I cannot work out is what to put in the onClick to make the function this.register = function() fire.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I don't know how you can write code and not know how to use it.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Register" onClick="nameOfFunction()">

Comment: well how do you initialize TaxiShare?

Comment: @espascarello TaxiShare is initialized with
      this.taxiShare = new TaxiShare();

Comment: use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) rather than trying to muck about with `onclick` attributes in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instance the class and use the object

```
function TaxiShare() {
this.register = function () { 
var username = get_name_value('name', 'user1'); 
$.post('http://website/users', {
    USERNAME: username
        }, function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (obj.status == "fail") {
                alert('User ' + username + ' is already registered.');
            } else {
                alert('User ' + username + ' has been successfully registered.');
            }
        }
        );
    }; 
}

var taxiShare = new TaxiShare();
```

And in the HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onClick="taxiShare.register()">
```

Comment: `TaxyShare` !== `TaxiShare`

Comment: Nice view ;) Updated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return this and assign make the taxiShare instance global - here's an example - https://jsfiddle.net/b2qjymwh/3/

```
<input type="button" value="Register" onClick="taxiShare.register();">

function TaxiShare() {
    this.register = function () { 
    $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .then(function (data) {    
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data);
    });    
    }

  return this;
}

taxiShare = new TaxiShare();
```